# How to improve background beacon scanning on Android O / New Google beacon API?

Tags: android, altbeacon, beacon

I am using the **awesome** Altbeacon Android Beacon Library to scan for beacons in my Android app. With Android O, this can take up to 25 minutes at times. Is there any way to get around this? I have heard talks of Google releasing its own beacon API to aid in the scanning of beacons, has anyone heard the same?

Answer (score 2):

To be clear, the 25 minutes it may take to detect beacons with the Android Beacon Library on Android 8.0 is a worst-case scenario based on other beacons being in the vicinity, and you wanting to detect additional beacons after the first ones are detected.  **The typical detection time is 5 seconds.**  You can read more about this [here](http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2017/08/07/beacon-detection-with-android-8).

Google does have its own [Nearby](https://developers.google.com/nearby/notifications/get-started) and other APIs bundled with Google Play Services which can be used to detect beacons, but they are subject to the same power saving rules and in theory the same delays.  Because the projects are closed-source, details of the times it takes these libraries to detect beacons are a bit of a mystery.  Plenty of users report significant delays or no detections at all.  Again, because it is closed source, there is no easy way to know what causes detection delays.